# Adding Eventhandler to MyButton in a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, delegates, event-handling, visual-studio-2013, tablelayoutpanel

I need to add an event handler to MyButton that is in a TableLayoutPanel.  I've looked through Stackoverflow and several other sight and I'm not getting it. What I have is a function that gets the control from the TableLayoutPanel.

```
Public Function AddEventHandler(ByVal iColumnIndex As Integer, ByVal iRowIndex As Integer, ByVal eh As Action(Of EventHandler)) As Boolean
    Dim bReturn As Boolean = False
    m_TblLoPnl.GetControlFromPosition(iColumnIndex, iRowIndex)
    Return bReturn
End Function
```

But cannot find what I need to do to assign MyButton.Click event an eventhandler. MyButton inherits the Button class which I know has a click event.

This is what I have added so far to pass a function in through AddEventHandler

```
Public Function AddEventHandler(ByVal iColumnIndex As Integer, ByVal iRowIndex As Integer, ByRef func As Object) As Boolean
    Dim bReturn As Boolean = False
    m_TmpBtn = m_TblLoPnl.GetControlFromPosition(iColumnIndex, iRowIndex)
    AddEventHandler(m_TmpBtn.Click, AddressOf func)
    Return bReturn
End Function

Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
```

Comment: Did you mean vb.Net instead of vba possibly?  You might want to change the tag if so.

Comment: No this is a desktop application... At this point :)

Comment: I mean, are you using Visual Basic / Visual Studios?  VBA = Visual Basic for Applications.  VBA doesn't have EventHandlers (as such) or a Return statement...

Comment: Using visual Studio.net 2013.  Ok that does need to be changed then

Comment: You'll probably get some more answers now ;)  Incidentally, a quick google search brought me to [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/127f72c8-d68b-4e4f-a204-aaaae5cdf5e9/add-event-handler-to-buttons-on-tablelayoutpanel), which might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks that didn't come up on my search

Comment: I don't mind being down voted but I would appreciate a comment on why so I can avoid the behavior in the future

Comment: Look at my updated code sample in the answer below.  You shouldn't have the parenthesis in the addeventhandler statement.  and you shouldn't be declaring the click event like above.

Comment: I just noticed that you have `AddEventHandler`.  It should be `AddHandler`.  Unless you wrote your own method named `AddEventHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that GetControlFromPosition returns an object of type button.  If doesn't return an object of type button you'll have to add some additional type checking and conversion before attempting to add the handler.

```
Public Function AddEventHandler(ByVal iColumnIndex As Integer, ByVal iRowIndex As Integer, ByVal eh As Action(Of EventHandler)) As Boolean
    Dim bReturn As Boolean = False
    Dim foundButton as Button

    foundButton = m_TblLoPnl.GetControlFromPosition(iColumnIndex, iRowIndex)

    AddHandler foundButton.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler

    Return bReturn
End Function

Private Sub myClickHandler(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
        'Event Handler Code
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing that myClickhandler is a function someplace or is My ClickHandler come into via eh that I passed in?

Comment: "myClickHandler" should be the name of the method that you want to handle the button click.  Make sure that your handler method has the following signature ***private sub myClickHandler(sender as object, e as EventArgs)***